# xsl:for-each - How to format list?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new at this so please forgive me if I am being ignorant.  This is a sample of my XML data.

```
<record ID="ART5843">
  <title>This is a sample record</title>
  <edition></edition>
  <persauthorfull>Lykins, Amy D.</persauthorfull>
  <persauthorfull>Cantor, James M.</persauthorfull>
  <persauthorfull>Blanchard, Ray</persauthorfull>
  <keywords>Generic</keywords>
  <keywords>Criminal offences</keywords>
  <keywords>Civil offences</keywords>
  <keywords>Men</keywords>
  <keywords>Psychology</keywords>
  <keywords>Research</keywords>
  <subjects></subjects>
</record>
```

I need the `<persauthorfull>` to rename to `<PA>` and then to output on a single line separated by semi-colon, such...

```
<PA>Lykins, Amy D.; Cantor, James M.; Blanchard, Ray</PA>
```

I am using XSL for-each to extract the names, but I have no idea of how to format them.

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:persauthorfull">
  <PA>
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </PA>
</xsl:for-each>
```

From what I am surmising this is a single iteration over the author - is there another way?

Comment: Please show your full input XML (including the namespace definition, for instance) and a full stylesheet. What version of XSLT do you use?

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to put XML and XSLT snippets, we're not going to be able to help you much.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get:

```
<PA>Lykins, Amy D.; Cantor, James M.; Blanchard, Ray</PA>
```

then you should be doing (in XSLT 1.0):

```
<PA>
    <xsl:for-each select="persauthorfull">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</PA>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, `string-join()` is what you are looking for:

```
<PA>
   <xsl:value-of select="string-join(a:persauthorfull,'; ')"/>
</PA>
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by Michael Kay, there is an even simpler approach:

```
<xsl:value-of select="persauthorfull" separator="; "/>
```

Using either line of code, the text content of all `persauthorfull` elements is joined, delimited by "; ".

---

Let me also clear up what your current code does. You write:

> From what I am surmising this is a single iteration over the author

That's true - if by "single iteration" you mean one iteration for each `a:persauthorfull` element. This will create several `PA` elements in the output, if there is more than one author. Also, the name of the author ends up in an attribute `type`:

```
<PA type="Blanchard, Ray"/>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|persauthorfull[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>
            <PA>
                <xsl:value-of select="string-join(persauthorfull,'; ')"/>
            </PA>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="persauthorfull[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Input**

```
<record ID="ART5843">
  <title>This is a sample record</title>
  <edition></edition>
  <persauthorfull>Lykins, Amy D.</persauthorfull>
  <persauthorfull>Cantor, James M.</persauthorfull>
  <persauthorfull>Blanchard, Ray</persauthorfull>
  <keywords>Generic</keywords>
  <keywords>Criminal offences</keywords>
  <keywords>Civil offences</keywords>
  <keywords>Men</keywords>
  <keywords>Psychology</keywords>
  <keywords>Research</keywords>
  <subjects></subjects>
</record>
```

**XML Output**

```
<record ID="ART5843">
   <title>This is a sample record</title>
   <edition/>
   <PA>Lykins, Amy D.; Cantor, James M.; Blanchard, Ray</PA>
   <keywords>Generic</keywords>
   <keywords>Criminal offences</keywords>
   <keywords>Civil offences</keywords>
   <keywords>Men</keywords>
   <keywords>Psychology</keywords>
   <keywords>Research</keywords>
   <subjects/>
</record>
```

Comment: The XSLT 2.0 solution doesn't actually need string-join, you can simply write `<xsl:value-of select="perauthorfull" separator="; "/>`

Answer (score 0):

Following XSLT generates the output and can be adjusted to meet further unknown requirements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
<PA>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="persauthorfull"/>
</PA>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="persauthorfull">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PA>Lykins, Amy D.;Cantor, James M.;Blanchard, Ray</PA>
```

With "can be adjusted" I just meant - it's e.g. possible to omit the XML namespace-declaration, but maybe you want to keep it. As I suppose that you may want to add further information from your input later, this can be easily done extending the template.
In case you're new to XSLT, just as short info how this works - `<xsl:template match="/*">` matches the whole input XML from root. Then `<xsl:apply-templates select="persauthorfull"/>` only applies templates to nodes named `persauthorfull`. As there is one template matching these nodes - `<xsl:template match="persauthorfull">`, the nodes are processed there. All other nodes will be omitted. And `<xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>;</xsl:text></xsl:if>` takes care about adding a `;` after each node value when its `position()` is not the `last()`.